# Two-way Computed Property with Vuejs class components

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, data-binding

Is it possible to use **two-way computed** properties with vuejs when using **class-style components**? In my case, given an app with a simple vuex store, is there a way to bind the store values to a **select** with `v-model`?

In the [vuex documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html) there is an example for two-way binding:

```js
// ...
computed: {
  message: {
    get () {
      return this.$store.state.obj.message
    },
    set (value) {
      this.$store.commit('updateMessage', value)
    }
  }
}
```

But I did not get this to work with class components. I tried something like

```typescript
private get myvalue(): boolean {
  return store.state.myvalue;
}

/* Same type of function I would use when using @input one-way binding*/
private set myvalue(e: Event /* Wrong type for the setter... */) {
  const target: HTMLSelectElement = e.target as HTMLSelectElement;
  const value = target.value;

  if (Boolean(value)) {
    store.commit("myvalue", target.value);
  }
}
```

But this obviously does not work because getters/setters always have the same data type. The type of `myvalue` is `bool`, but passing it to both functions does not work as well, because when binding to a `select` like so

```
<select v-model="myvalue">
  <option value="false">No</option>
  <option value="true">Yes</option>
</select>
```

The setter does not seem to get a value.

I also tried to bind the value to the `select` manually (like you would do with text-inputs) but using `:selected` on the `select` options didn't work (the first option always was selected).

Comment: If `myvalue` is a bool then maybe you need to make sure the option values are also bools instead of strings by doing `:value="false"` and `:value="true"`.

Comment: @DecadeMoon I'll look into that. I checked for that when testing if an option was selected but not when setting the value. Thanks for that hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working after a little while. Just using class setters and getters was the solution afterall:

```
<select v-model="myvalue">
  <option :value="false">No</option>
  <option :value="true">Yes</option>
</select>
```

and

```
private get myvalue(): boolean {
  return store.state.myvalue;
}

private set myvalue(value: boolean) {
  store.commit("myvalue", value);
}
```

work for the basic functionality.